# How to sort one list based on another?

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting

I have two list, one reference and one input list

```
Ref = [3, 2, 1, 12, 11, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4]
Input = [9, 5, 2, 3, 10, 4, 11, 8]
```

I want to sort Input list, in the order as that of Ref. If some element is missing in Input list, it can skip and go for the other element.

Hence sorted Input list, based on Ref list will be like this

```
Sorted_Input = [3, 2, 11, 10, 9, 8, 5, 4]
```

Comment: why not loop over reference list and check if items are in input list?
```new = [val for val in Ref if val in Input]```

Comment: @Georgy - the above question only keeps the elements as present in the other list, however I was looking for sorting as well, this is why it's a different question

Comment: There is no sorting here but just filtering. Please, see the accepted answer in the duplicate target. It is the same as the accepted answer here, and it will produce the same result as you want.

Comment: @Georgy - now I agree with you.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I think this answers your question:

```
>>> [x for x in Ref if x in Input]
>>> [3, 2, 11, 10, 9, 8, 5, 4]
```

Hope it helps.

**UPDATE**:
Making `Input` a `set` for faster access:

```
>>> Input_Set = set(Input)
>>> [x for x in Ref if x in Input_Set]
[3, 2, 11, 10, 9, 8, 5, 4]
```

Comment: This probably doesn't matter to the questioner since they accepted the answer, but beware this deduplicates `Input` as well as sorting it. For example, `[1, 1, 1, 3]` goes to `[3, 1]`.

Comment: @SteveJessop I know, at some point the OP said `Input`'s elements were all different. Now I'm confused, I thought this answer had several comments on that.

Comment: @SteveJessop - my input and ref will never have duplicates, so yes this solution will always be valid

Answer (score 8):

Another approach in addition to dcg's answer would be as follows:

```
Ref = [3, 2, 1, 12, 11, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4]
Input = [9, 5, 2, 3, 10, 4, 11, 8]

ref = set(Ref)
inp = set(Input)

sorted_list = sorted(ref.intersection(inp), key = Ref.index)
```

This outputs to:

```
[3, 2, 11, 10, 9, 8, 5, 4]
```

Here you convert the lists into sets, find their intersection, and sort them. The set is sorted based on the 'Ref' list's indexing.

Answer (score 8):

You can use the sorted method:

```
# keep in a dict the index for each value from Ref
ref  = {val: i for i, val in enumerate(Ref)}
# sort by the index value from Ref for each number from Input 
sorted(Input, key=ref.get)
```

output:

```
[3, 2, 11, 10, 9, 8, 5, 4]
```

Answer (score 6):

Here's the naive approach:

```
sorted(Input, key=Ref.index)
```

Or in-place:

```
Input.sort(key=Ref.index)
```

Either way it's just one line.

Although I think it's slow -- O(n*m) where n and m are the lengths of `Input` and `Ref`. [@rusu_ro1's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59480385/4518341) uses a similar method but seems to be O(n+m).

Comment: Technically I guess any other solution is premature optimization unless we know the inputs will be large enough that the speed matters.

Comment: @JollyJoker very true, thanks for mentioning

Comment: @JollyJoker And without knowing exactly what kind of elements are in the real list (duplicates/unique elements, hashable or not, etc).